# django make log that works for all models

Tags: django, string, join

I am trying to make my own log that makes a string of changed data between object (my old object and my new object) However i keep getting back empty string,

My code:

```
def log_fields(old_obj, new_obj):
    fields = new_obj.__class__._meta.fields
    changed_fields = ""
    old_data = ""
    new_data = ""

    # get all changed data
    for field in fields:
        old_field_data = old_obj.__getattribute__(field.name)
        new_field_data = new_obj.__getattribute__(field.name)

        if old_field_data != new_field_data:
            count =+ 1
            # convert changed data to strings   
            # number + space + data + 5 spaces for next string
            changed_fields.join(str(count)).join(" ").join(str(field)).join("     ")
            old_data.join(str(count)).join(" ").join(str(old_field_data)).join("     ")
            new_data.join(str(count)).join(" ").join(str(new_field_data)).join("     ")

    print changed_fields
    print old_data
    print new_data
```

I got a feeling something with the string .join combination something is going wrong, cause trying this manually in shell seems to work up to the comparison. Not sure tho hos i should change the string

Comment: Assume that the objects are the same, this function is called after saving?

Comment: Yes indeed, so i looks for the changed beween the old object version and the new version.  (figured out atm some .joins are going horribly wrong:P)

Answer (score 0):

```
changed_fields = changed_fields + str(count) + "." + str(field.name) + "     "
old_data = old_data + str(count) + "." + str(old_field_data) + "     "
new_data = new_data + str(count) + "." + str(new_field_data) + "     "
```

Seems to do the job,  so for now, ill keep it at this